# What is a "sea laser"?

Tags: meaning, terminology, eggcorn, malapropisms

A client has sent me a document with the word "sea laser" as part of a list of additional services chiropractors offer in the United States. I've looked under "sea laser", "sea laser acupuncture", and "sea laser therapy" and nothing shows up. Has anybody seen this term before? Does anybody know what it means?

<sub>**EDIT**:</sub>

This is what the client sent in a table of items, so many items are not separated by a comma:

> "Additional services chiropractors provide: Acupuncture and its variations (meridian therapy; acupuncture without needles, or **sea laser**; electro-acupuncture) Physical Therapy Physiotherapy Sports Medicine Naturopathy Nutrition Pilates Radiography Flexion / Distraction Corrective Exercises Detox Homeopathic Products Yoga Rehabilitation Auriculotherapy."

That is all I have

Comment: Can you please give a lengthier quote so that strings like 'deep-sea laser-induced breakdown spectrometer' can be discounted.

Comment: Instead of "or sea", perhaps it was a pronunciation of the individual letters "R" and "C". Googling around, I found this: [RC laser pens](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/rc-laser-pen.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has become very probable that it is based on an erroneous attempt to convert from the spoken word.

Answer (score 10):

The only thing I can think of is *cold laser*.

I don't know anything about chiropractic medicine, but the term "cold laser" seems to be something that Google associates with chiropractors.

I can only assume that someone was dictating the document that was sent to you, and a chiropractor somewhere must refer to "cold lasers" as "c-lasers", and someone transcribed that as *sea lasers*.

Comment: Sorry, Ron.  I didn't see your post before posting mine.  LLLT is also known as "cold laser".

Comment: I'd say mystery solved! :)

Comment: You got my vote.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps they meant SHR? [SHR lasers](https://www.spectrumsciencebeauty.com.au/super-hair-removal-shr-laser-hair-removal-machine/) are used in hair removal. SHR stands for Super Hair Removal.  They deliver enough energy to the hair to kill the root but not so much as to damage the surrounding skin.

Chiropractors might offer [Low Level Laser Therapy (LLLT)](https://www.spine-health.com/treatment/pain-management/cold-laser-therapy-pain-management-treatment).

S-E-A provides [3D scanning lasers](http://www.sealimited.com/capability/3d-laser-scanning) so that is not it.

If there is a contact number you can try calling them.